# Translation of errors in form fields in prestashop 1.7

Tags: forms, field, translation, prestashop-1.7

Where can I translate the error that throws this form field in the template classic ?. I have searched in translations but it does not show it.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, this message is set by the browser, not PrestaShop. More information here https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html5-form-validation-with-the-pattern-attribute--cms-25145

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the wanted behavior by adding this to the field code (search for the code in tpl):

```
oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Here put your custom text!')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')"
```

So let's say you have the password field, you will have something like this:

```
<input type="password" oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Here put your custom text!')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')" />
```